# Python Sqlite adding a row

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a local sqlite server. The SQL database only contains a table called `flights`. This table `flights` only contains two columns: `dt` and `flight`. It is created like so: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flight (dt INT NOT NULL, flight INT PRIMARY KEY);`. `dt` is meant to stand for datetime. This column `dt` holds time and date stamps for each flight. The `flight` column is meant to be an auto increment id for each flight.

I now need to create the flight and record the ID. But I think my method below is incredibly stupid. There has to be a better way than this. The code below does not work thus adding to the stupidity of my attempt. It returns currently prints `(None,)`.

For added clarification, all I need to do is add a flight with the provided time stamp. Then find the id of the flight I just created. Should be simple enough.

```
t = (int(time.time()),)
conn, c = AT.startSQLdb()
c.execute("INSERT INTO flight VALUES (?,NULL);",t)
c.execute("SELECT flight FROM flight WHERE dt=?;",t)
print c.fetchone()
conn.commit()
```

By the way, `AT.startSQLdb()` is just a method that returns a tuple `(sql connection, sql cursor)`. I just have it as a function to keep the start up functionality the same for all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the last auto-assigned id with this SQL:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

BTW: you mention threads, SQLite is not great with concurrent access, so be careful with multiple threads.

Comment: For the same effect, from python you can call to:         c.lastrowid